# How to add hover effect to <table> using CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I draw a table in CKEditor.

You can see current my table look like this.

[image]

Currently, I want to hover columns of the table and it will auto highlights check icon with the colour orange.

I found to change CSS:

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/mycustom.css';
CKEDITOR.replace('myfield');
```

I don't know how to apply in the table.

My table has structure like:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Havent worked on ckeditor ,but thought to give it a go now.Quick question , are you using the table plugin to generate the tables ?

Comment: Only using default tool to create a table on Toolbar. I not using any plugin. http://ckeditor.com/demo#full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script to highlight columns where there is checkmarks with an orange background-color.

```
var CKE = $( '.editor' );
CKE.ckeditor();
var columnIndex=0;

$("#update").click(function(){
    // Output CKEditor's result in a result div
    $("#result").html(CKE.val());

    // If there is a table in the result
    if( $("#result").find("table") ){
        console.log("Table found.");

        // On mouse over a td
        $("#result").find("td").on("mouseover",function(){
            // find the column index
            columnIndex = $(this).index();

            // Condition is to ensure no highlighting on the 2 firsts columns
            if(columnIndex>1){
                $(this).closest("table").find("tr").each(function(){
                    var thisTD = $(this).find("td").eq(columnIndex);

                    // If cell is not empty
                    //   &nbsp; is the html entity for a space
                    //   CKEditor always insert a space in "empty" cells.
                    if( thisTD.html() != "&nbsp;" ){
                        thisTD.addClass("highlight");
                    }
                });
            }

            // Clear all hightlights
        }).on("mouseout",function(){
            $(this).closest("table").find("td").removeClass("highlight");
        });
    }

    // Console log the resulting HTML (Usefull to post HTML on StackOverflow!!!)
    console.log("\n"+CKE.val())
});
```

I took the time to make a demo based on your table.
Please, next time, post your HTML!!!

See working demo on [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wzNbYO?editors=1010)

Comment: I appreciate it! Build an answer base on my table is not your language. You are awesome. Thanks

Comment: Actually... Trying to master languages like javascript and many others... Vietnamese ain't a problem (Thanks to Google translate!!!). 
Tốt ngày cho bạn

Comment: Thank you @louyspatricebessette, that really interesting.